# Converting variables to dates in R

Tags: r, datetime

There is a matrix with two columns: years and months

```
dates.m
1492 April
1492 August
1492 October
```

How to convert these two variables into a date format variable (for example `mm/yyyy`)? Thanks.

Comment: date also needs a day.  So, if you have a data.frame, `as.Date(paste(do.call(paste,df1), '01'), '%Y %B %d')`

Comment: Or you can use `sapply` to apply the above function on the all elemnts of a matrix.

Comment: I have added the day data and now it's a data frame with 3 variables (year, day, month). But the function you showed creates a vector of NAs.

Comment: You have days before months where the command provided is months before days - try `as.Date(do.call(paste,datetest), '%Y %d %B')`

Comment: @JayBlack Still a bunch of NAs. Could this be because the days in my data don' have zero in front of single digit numbers? e.g., `7` instead of `07`?
Ah, it works now. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
dates.m<-data.frame(dates.m,stringsAsFactors=F)
dfl=split(dates.m,1:nrow(dates.m))
dates.m$data=do.call(rbind,lapply(dfl,function(rn)
paste(as.Date(paste(paste(rn,collapse = "/"),"01",sep="/"),"%Y/%b/%d"),sep="")))
dates.m$data
```

> ```
>   [,1]        
> 1 "1492-04-01"
> 2 "1492-08-01"
> 3 "1492-10-01"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to dates I love working with the `lubridate` package. here the example code to solve this, if you have one column containing the data (assuming your data is ordered in the way of year-month-day - change the order of the letters in the function name otherwise):

```
require(lubridate)
df$date<-ymd(df$dates.m)
```

or if you have them in seperate columns:

```
require(lubridate)
require(stringr)
df$date<-ymd(str_c(as.character(df$Year),as.character(df$Month),
                   as.character(df$Day),sep="-"))
```